# SQL Server Group By Durations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express, group-by

After some searching, I was able to get results using this query.

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, LOGINTIME, LOGOUTTIME) 
FROM 
    [SESSION]
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(YEAR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
    DATEPART(MONTH, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
    DATEPART(DAY, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
    DATEPART(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)) / 10),
    LoginTime, LogoutTime
```

It is a table having sessions of user login and logout times. What I want exactly is to calculate how many users were having an hour two or more. I want to get the count.

A sample result from this query was.

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
4
17
20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to do it using this query after adding "SessionDuration" as a computed column with "LogoutTime-LoginTime".

```
SELECT COUNT(DATEPART(HOUR,SessionDuration)) AS [Count],
       DATEPART(HOUR,SessionDuration) AS SessionDuration 
FROM [SESSION]
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,SessionDuration)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making it in to a subquery and grouping and filtering the results like so:

```
SELECT Hours, COUNT(T1.Hours) HourCount
FROM 
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME) as Hours
    FROM [SESSION]
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART(YEAR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
        DATEPART(MONTH, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
        DATEPART(DAY, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
        DATEPART(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
        (DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)) / 10),
        LoginTime,LogoutTime) T1
GROUP BY T1.Hours
HAVING T1.Hours > 1
```

This will split and count by `Hours` where it is more than 1.

Comment: For both i am getting incorrect Syntax near group by and near having.

Comment: Sorry, I've tested the above modified version on some sample data now, so it should produce results.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'T1'.

Comment: I have updated again, left an extra comma in the select statement

Comment: Whatever works for you. You are obviously able to modify your table design, where as the other answers here simply attempt to answer the question that was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(Total) AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ROW_MUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(HOUR, LOGINTIME, LOGOUTTIME)) AS Total 
    FROM 
        [SESSION]
    WHERE
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, LOGINTIME, LOGOUTTIME) > 1
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART(YEAR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
        DATEPART(MONTH, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
        DATEPART(DAY, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
        DATEPART(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)),
        (DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(HOUR,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME)) / 10),
        LoginTime, LogoutTime
) AS T
```

Comment: it says ROW_NUMBER() is invalid

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 Express Edition